# Почему React Redux не работает с spring boot

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, redux

Есть заготовка для web приложения, в которой `React` + `Redux` должены работать с `Spring Boot`. Хотя на странице должно быть содержимое `WebPage`. Но ничего нет.

В консоли появляется ошибка с `import "babel-polyfill";` в `reducers/index.js`. Тоесть импорта не происходит хотя библиотека подгрузилась и в IDE ссылка рабочая.

Только начал учить `react` помогите пожалуйста решить эту проблему. Спасибо.

Вот такая структура приложения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это `index.html` :

```
<div id="base-container"></div>

<script type="text/babel" th:src="@{/index.js}" ></script>
</body>
```

Это `reducers/index.js` :

```
import 'babel-polyfill'
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
import {createStore} from 'redux';
import allReducers from "./reducers/index";
import WebPage from './components/WebPage'

const store = createStore(allReducers);

ReactDOM.render(

    <Provider store={store}>
        <WebPage/>
    </Provider>,

    document.getElementById('base-container')
);
```

Это `reducers/car.js` :

```
export default function () {
    return [
        {
            id: 1,
            model: 'Audi',
            speed: 400
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            model: 'BMW',
            speed: 300
        }
    ]
}
```

Это `reducers/index.js` :

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import CarsReducers from './car';

const allReducers = combineReducers({
    cars: CarsReducers
});

export default allReducers;
```

Это `components/WebPage.js` :

```
import React from 'react';

const WebPage = () => (
    <div>
        <h3>Cars:</h3>
        <hr/>
        <h3>Details:</h3>
    </div>
);

export default WebPage;
```

Мой `package.json`:

```
{
 "name": "react-spring",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "This is sample of freanding react and spring boot",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
  "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-regenerator": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "react": "latest",
    "react-dom": "latest",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.8.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "test"
  },
  "presets": [
    "latest"
  ],
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "react-spring-boot-sample"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "1"
  ],
  "author": "Pavel_Ravvich",
  "license": "UNLICENSED"
}
```

Spring security если что отключен `.antMatchers("/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()`

Буду очень признателен за любые подсказки.

Comment: А где именно вы взяли заготовку? Сбросьте пожалуйста ссылочку на гит.

Comment: @alexandr gaiduchok Проблема несколько конкретезировалась, я обновил вопрос. К сожалению это моя заготовка, ссылка на гит: https://github.com/triodjangopiter/react-redux-spring-boot готовые заготовки не нашел к сожалению, хотелось понять как оно должно работать.

Comment: А здесь смотрели? https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/react-and-spring-data-rest/

Comment: Проблема на этапе сборке webpack'ом на сколько я понимаю. Нужно добавить в entry данную строку

Comment: Посмотрите сюда https://habrahabr.ru/company/alfa/blog/340776/